# BoxWhiskerChart - 10-90th percentile instead of min - max

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, charts

I am trying to draw a custom `BoxWhiskerChart` with alternative values determining fences. 
I have data that has a lot of outliers and I have to compare it to another chart that has 10-90th percentile instead of standard min/max.

How would I go about it?

Comment: Hi ! Do you have any code you can share with us ?

Comment: Hi,data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200]; BoxWhiskerChart[data] is the function I am using. Nothing more fancy about it. I am wondering if there is a way to modify the specification of what is a fence - ie instead of min-max - I would like it to be 10-th and 90th percentile.

Comment: I would imagine it is possible to draw boxes, I am not sure how to use mathematica function draw[] to plot fences.

Answer (score 15):

With the data beeing

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
```

the range of the box specified to be one sigma (approx. 68.3 %tile range) by

```
sigma=Erf[1/Sqrt[2]]
```

and a limit for the fences defined to be 10 %

```
fencesLimit = 0.1
```

we can plot a `BoxWhiskerChart` using:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Median", 
 Method -> 
  "BoxRange" -> 
   (Quantile[#, {fencesLimit, (1 - sigma)/2, 1/2, (1 + sigma)/2, 1 - fencesLimit}, 
      {{1/3, 1/3}, {0, 1}}] &)]
```

This BoxWhisker is median centered, has a box range of one sigma, a lower fence at the 10 percentile, and an upper fence at the 90 percentile.
You can find in the documentation of [`Quantile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantile.html) how to choose another centering.

Here a plot of this BoxWhiskerChart:

[image: Out1]

With some additional styling and as a function with optional arguments:

```
bwChart[data_, br_: Erf[1/Sqrt[2]], flimit_: 0.1] := 
   BoxWhiskerChart[data, 
   {{"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[Thickness[0.01], Blue]}, {"MedianNotch", 0.5, Gray}},
   Method -> "BoxRange" -> (Quantile[#, {flimit, (1 - br)/2, 1/2, (1 + br)/2, 1 - flimit}, 
     {{1/3, 1/3}, {0, 1}}] &), 
   BarSpacing -> None, AspectRatio -> 0.7, BarOrigin -> Left, 
   ChartElementFunction -> "GlassBoxWhisker", ChartStyle -> 6]

bwChart[data]
```

[image: Out2]

---

Using Mathematica version 11.0.0 the output of `bwChart[data]` is

[image: Out_v11]

---

A direct comparison of the same `data` as a 10th to 90th %tile `BoxWhiskerChart` with an `"Outliers"` and a standard min/max `BoxWhiskerChart`.

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];

Show[{
  BoxWhiskerChart[{data, Null, Null}, "Outliers", 
   Method -> 
    {"BoxRange" -> (Quantile[#, {10/100, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 90/100}, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}] &)}], 
  BoxWhiskerChart[{Null, data, Null}, "Outliers"],
  BoxWhiskerChart[{Null, Null, data}]
  }]
```

[image: Out4]

Comment: (+1) Thank you! Spent hours to make `BoxRange` work as an option :)

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you for the clear explanation!

Comment: @Masi Did you use `bwChart[data]` to produce the output? It wasn't part of the posted code block before my latest edit, which also shows the output I get using version 11. If you are still having problems, please be more specific of what you cannot reproduce.

Comment: @Masi For me replacing `data` with `{data1, data2}` does produce the expected output. Here is [a screen snipped](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YKsd0.png) of the in- and output I used to test it. Did I misunderstand you or does that solve your problem? (I'm not sure what you mean with "with other data sources in the same figure".)

Comment: @Masi Please see my edit. I'd use `Show` to combine these different kinds of `BoxWhiskerChart`s into one graph.

Comment: @Masi If your data doesn't have any outliers, then that is expected. Also having very few data points can result in all `BoxWhiskerChart`s looking the same. Here is [one example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLE3P.png). The relatively big boxes in your image certainly makes it look like you don't have a lot of data point and that they are relative uniformly distributed.

Comment: @Karsten7. I have 60 data points so it should be enough. Here is the CSV data file which I am using http://www.sharecsv.com/s/a665054ee9be03eb1176351715c4efdb/10prac.csv

Comment: @Masi The `BoxWhiskerChart`s are correct for your data. You can compare `Quantile[data, {10/100, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 90/100}, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}]` with `MinMax@data` and also use `Histogram[data, {1}, "PDF"]` for verification.

Comment: why are the outliers gone if `BoxRange` method is used?

Comment: @Karsten7. This behavior is very unexpected. Any idea to get the outliers back while keeping the newly defined fences?